# set style for QWidgetItem PyQt

Tags: pyqt

I have a layout named self.box

and I want to select one of the indexes of this layout with the `itemAt` method

and change the related style

but i get this error:

```
'QWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'
```

Note that I know that I can style each of the buttons separately

But I want to know if there is a way to style the QWidgetItem

code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
        

class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.box)

        self.button = QPushButton('button1')
        self.button2 = QPushButton('button2')
        self.button3 = QPushButton('button3')
        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button3)


        self.box.itemAt(1).setStyleSheet('background-color:red;')
        

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.show()
    

app = QApplication([])
m = main()
m.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: [QWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidgetitem.html) is not a widget, it's a [*layout item*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayoutitem.html) that is used by layout managers as a reference for their purposes, so there's nothing to "style" there because it's not a visual element. Only widgets can be styled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
self.box.itemAt(1).widget().setStyleSheet('background-color:red')
```